# Make git just *copy* (not merge)?

Tags: git, tags, git-merge

How can I tell git "make this branch HEAD look just like this other branch HEAD"?

We have some history of developing on `develop`, branching for releases, and doing whatever it takes to make the release branch work. But we've been lax about updating `master`. Fortunately, we have tags for what was actually released. We want now, post hoc, to make `master` be the series of released versions.

This is more than just resolving all merge conflicts "theirs"; I want all *differences* resolved "theirs", if you will. If, for example, during the `release/1` process we added **x = x + 1;** to *Foo.java*, but never added that to `develop` or `release/2`, then when we deliver `release/1` to `master`, this line should be there, but by the time we've delivered `release/2` to `master`, it should disappear. Understand, there's no change anywhere in the history that removes the line; it just was added only to a dead-end branch.

Also, I think `git rebase ....` isn't what I want: I don't want to lose the deep history. Once I've successfully done this for releases 1 through 37, `git log master` should show all the changes that actually contributed to each release (and, likely, some merge fix-up commits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout -B master release/X       # release/X is the new master version
```

is what you want.  Nothing in the current `master` history is relevant as you're just taking `release/X` whole.

If you really really have to keep the abandoned history reachable from your active work,

```
git checkout -B master release/X       # release/X is the new master version
git merge -s ours --no-ff master@{1}
```

but there's not much reason for that.   You could tag it instead, if it's even worth that.

Comment: I like jthill's even better than torek's, because it preserves history (git log). True, that's only a "nice to have" for me, and indeed my original statement made it seem actually undesired (so the fault lies not in torek's suggestion). Guess I've evolved!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you basically want to make one new commit on `master` that, in effect, removes everything that was under `master` and replaces it all with everything that was (and still is) under `release/X`.

There are shorter and faster ways to do this, but I'll show you the slower method first, because I think it's clearer.  Note that this assumes you're at the top level of the git directory (`git rev-parse --show-cdup` will tell you how many `../`'s you may need to go up to that level):

```
$ git checkout master           # onto the branch we want to whack
$ git rm -rf .                  # remove everything
$ git checkout release/X -- .   # repopulate index and work tree
$ git commit                    # and commit the result
```

If this really is what you want to do, note that you can do this quicker with `git commit-tree`, which adds a new commit to the repository by taking the given tree-ID and parent-IDs.  Since the desired new tree is 100% identical to some existing tree (that of `release/X`), you need only identify the desired parent commit (presumably whatever `master` points to initially), create the new commit, and make `master` point to that, without bothering with the index and work-tree.  If you have a lot of these release/N items to do, it will be faster this way, it's just a bit trickier.

Comment: It not that trickier with `commit-tree`: `git commit-tree -p master release/X^{tree}`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: sure, but that produces the new commit ID on stdout.  You must then use `git update-ref` to update `master` to point to the new commit—or, in the case of making a series of these, just keep looping with each new commit using the previous one as its parent, and do one update at the end.  (Which is what I was getting at, but didn't have time to write up in detail.)